# Different results with the same keywords in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question to understand the search logic. I have an Elasticsearch 5.4 instance and make a query_string query. The default operator is OR. Other settings are not defined.
Now I search for

```
dog house
```

and get 10,500 results. Then I search for

```
house dog
```

and get only 6,200 results. That's a bit curious for me.

That's my query:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "query_string" : {
                        "query" : "dog house~",
                        "default_operator" : "OR",
                        "fuzziness" : "AUTO"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term" : {
                        "client" : {
                            "value" : "MyClient",
                            "boost" : 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range" : {
                        "dateCreate" : {
                            "gte" : "2000-01-01T00:00:00+0200",
                            "lte" : "2000-12-31T23:59:59+0200"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size" : 2,
    "from" : 0,
    "sort" : [
        {
            "_score" : {
                "order" : "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "collapse" : {
        "field" : "title.keyword"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your complete query please?

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the `~` operator. If you try removing it and running the query again the number should be the same if the query is `dog house` or `house dog`.

Even the number of results should be the same if you run `dog house~` or `house~ dog`, but the number will change if you change the `~` from house to dog.

If you want both words to specify the transpositions distance of 1 that the fuzzy search can match you can try with `house~ dog~` and then the results will be the same if you change the order.